# User Defaults in swift 3 not working

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults

i have to save the password locally on my device by using the UserDefaults but it is not saving any value this is my code :

```
// this is for the bool value but not saving i don't know
var reg = true

let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
userDefault.set(reg, forKey: "reg")
let getBoolValue = userDefault.bool(forKey: "reg")


// this also for the string value but also not working
let userDefaul = UserDefaults.standard
userDefault.set("123456", forKey: "password")
let getPassword = userDefault.value(forKey: "password") as? String
```

Comment: Are you trying that at playground? You need to test it in a real project.

Comment: yes i try it on the project but when i reset the simulator it is work thank you my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are trying it at playground. Try it in a real project.

But would like to point out a typo here:

```
let userDefaul = UserDefaults.standard
userDefault.set("123456", forKey: "password")
let getPassword = userDefault.value(forKey: "password") as? String
```

You are using `userDefault` here again, instead of `userDefaul`

Also the earlier code would also work but just that you were trying to use `userDefaul` so thought of pointing out. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend

Comment: @HaiderAhmed: no problem, keep coding.. please upvote.. Cheers! :)